# #DocuSignAPI Unspecified_Error

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use CreateEnvelopesFromTemplatesAndForms.

I have used the PDF that I am uploading effectively using the simple CreateEnvelope.  I have also used the PDF effectively by manually uploading it via the Web UI.  So I don't think the error relates to the PDF.

Any hints on how to troubleshoot "Unspecified_Error" ?

Comment: I think hint #1 is to provide more information.  What are you calling, what's the PDF, what environment are you accessing...  you know :)

Comment: You should post the envelope body that you are creating using the `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms` call, you must be doing something wrong with how you're creating it if the doc works through the Console and through the `CreateEnvelope` call.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading SoapUI from SmartBear, then create a new SOAP Project and point it at DocuSign's WSDL: https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?WSDL. SoapUI will create sample calls for each of the DocuSign SOAP methods in the WSDL.

The error message you're getting means (generally) that you're not providing a field value that's required, or you have included a node tree that isn't necessarily required but since you included it, all of the values need to be valid.